# How does c# System.Type Type have a name property

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, abstract

I'm pretty sure this is related to implementing interfaces and inheritance.

In c# how does the System.Type class have the property Name? When I example the code of the Type class from metadata or using the Object Browser I see the Type class doesn't have:

```
string Name
```

defined anywhere.

I also see that Type inherits from MemberInfo and implements _Type and IReflect (like this):

```
public abstract class Type : MemberInfo, _Type, IReflect
```

The base class MemberInfo has the property:

```
public abstract string Name { get; }
```

From what I know, this **has** to be overridden in the derived class because of the abstract modifier. I don't see it in Type...

Then in the _Type interface there is a property:

```
string Name { get; }
```

and because that is in an interface it has no implementation of its own either.

Where is Name getting defined and how do it have a value in the System.Type class? Or am I not understanding how inheritance and implementing interfaces works for this class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that `System.Type` is itself an abstract class. That means it can be overriden in a subclass. In fact, you can see that types at run-time are not actually `System.Type`'s if you do something like this:

```
typeof(Type).GetType().FullName; // System.RuntimeType
```

The `System.RuntimeType` is an internal type that you won't see in the documentation, but it *does* override the `Name` property. It looks a little like this:

```
namespace System
{
    internal class RuntimeType : Type, ISerializable, ICloneable
    {
        ...
        public override string Name
        {
            get { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

---

See this note in the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx):

> **Type** is an abstract base class that allows multiple implementations. The system will always provide the derived class RuntimeType. In reflection, all classes beginning with the word Runtime are created only once per object in the system and support comparison operations.

Answer (score 1):

The abstract property `Name` from `MemberInfo` is indeed inherited by `System.Type`.

The reason why `System.Type` can implement the interface, is that an abstract instance member is allowed to implement an interface, as long as that member is public, of course, which `Name` is. Members that implement interfaces can be inherited from base classes.

The reason why `System.Type` is allowed to *not* override the `Name` property, is that `System.Type` is itself an abstract class. So it can "leave" the abstract member with no implementation. Non-abstract types deriving from it must still give an implementation for this property (its `get` accessor).

Whenever you have a variable `Type t = ...;` and call `t.Name` on it, the ***run-time type*** of `t` will have to be some non-abstract class, and that class will have an implementation of `Name`.